# How to get value from one form and post to the another form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am having two forms in same page,
Form 1 ID : home /
Form 2 ID : contact
I need the values filled in the form(home) in the text box of form2(contact) once the send button clicked.

```html
<form id="home" method="get" action="#portfolio" role="form"> 
  <select class="form-control" id="pd_howmuch">
         <option>HOW MUCH ?</option>
         <option>$100</option>
         <option>$200</option>
        </select>
        <input id="pd_fname" type="text" name="name">
        <input id="pd_lname" type="text" name="surname">
        <input id="pd_zipcode" type="tel" name="zipcode">
        <input id="pd_applynowbt" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
<section id="portfolio">
<form id="contact" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
       <select class="form-control" id="howmuch1">
         <option>HOW MUCH ?</option>
         <option>$100</option>
         <option>$200</option>
        </select>
        <input id="fname1" type="text" name="name">
        <input id="lname2" type="text" name="surname">
        <input id="zipcode2" type="tel" name="zipcode">
        <input id="applynowbt" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: This looks very wrong. Could you post an image showing how you want it to look like?

Comment: Why do this? Why not put the input fields into the same form?

Comment: Please visit http://sundarrajan360.co.nf/ , in home page we have one form and once apply now clicked it will direct to next form in the same page but it has value more than the first form.

Comment: This is not possible requirement or at least, it is not logical. Press send or submit button should lead to new page loading or page reload

Answer (score 0):

Ok If I am understanding you correctly you wish to populate information  from the first form to the second one.

So for this task to be accomplish you need to attach an event handler to the second form and prevent the default behavior

Working [demo](https://jsbin.com/duveyodeho/edit?html,js,output)  Hope to help you

```
var homeForm = document.getElementById("home");

var contactForm = document.getElementById("contact");
contactForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    contactForm.elements.item(0).value = homeForm.elements.item(0).value
    contactForm.elements.item(1).value = homeForm.elements.item(1).value
    contactForm.elements.item(2).value = homeForm.elements.item(2).value
    contactForm.elements.item(3).value = homeForm.elements.item(3).value

}, false);
```

Comment: Can you share more information. What error do you get. Are you shore you prevent the default behavior of the second form. Did you try the example in the demo

Comment: Yeah i have tried in demo its not worked and i am not get any error. When i am included your code in my code it works as previous no change.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sourceForm = document.getElementById("source-form");
var targetForm = document.getElementById("target-form");

function findTargetNode(nodeName, name) {
 
 var targetElems = targetForm.elements;
 
 for (var i = 0; i < targetElems.length; i++) {
  
  var elem = targetElems.item(i);
  
  if (elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === nodeName && elem.name === name) {
   return elem;
  }
 }
}

function setNodeValue(node, type, value) {
 
 if (type === 'select')
 {
  for (var i = 0, options = node.options; i < options.length; i++) {
   
   if (options[i].value === value) {
    options[i].setAttribute('selected', 'true');
   }
   else {
    options[i].removeAttribute('selected');
   }
  }
 }
 // else if (type === 'checkbox' || type === 'radio') { /* ... */ }
 else {
  node.value = value;
 }
}


sourceForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    
 for (var i = 0, elems = sourceForm.elements; i < elems.length; i++) {
  
  var elem = elems.item(i);
  
  if (!elem.name) {
   continue;
  }
  
  var type = elem.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  var targetNode = findTargetNode(type, elem.name);
  
  if (!targetNode) {
   continue;
  }
  
  setNodeValue(targetNode, type, elem.value);
 }
 
 e.preventDefault();
 // targetForm.submit();
 
}, false);
```

```html
    <form id="source-form" action="javascript:void(0)" role="form">
  <select class="form-control" id="my-select" name="my-select">
   <option value="-1">HOW MUCH ?</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <input id="my-text" type="text" name="my-text">
  <input id="submit-source-form" type="submit" value="Fill the following form">
 </form>
 
    <section style="margin-top: 15px;">
  <form id="target-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
   <select class="form-control" id="my-select-2" name="my-select">
    <option value="-1">HOW MUCH ?</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
   </select>
   <input id="my-text-2" type="text" name="my-text" value="this will change">
   
   <input id="additional-value" type="text" name="additional" placeholder="this value will not change">
   <input id="submit-target-form" type="submit" value="Send form">
  </form>
    </section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cremugnt/

Note: "Send form" action doesn't work here because of "Blocked form submission to 'http://stacksnippets.net/contact.php' because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set."

Note: This snippet can copy only "select" and "input" fields so if you want to work with other fields like "checkbox" or "radio" you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more global approach using [OODK-JS](https://github.com/GOMServices/oodk-js-oop-for-js) and jQuery compatible with any types of field (note as field matching is based on the name attribute ):

```
          $.noConflict();

          OODK.config({
            'path': {
              'oodk': '../src',
              'workspace': 'workspace'
            }
          });

          OODK(function($, _){

            // POO approach to solve this problem
            // define a FormHelper class
            var FormHelper = $.class(function($, µ, _){

              $.protected('form');

              $.public(function __initialize(form){
                  µ.form = form;
              });

              $.public(function exportToLiteral(){

                var exprt = {};

                jQuery(µ.form).find(":input, [textarea]").each(function(){

                  var val;

                  if(this.type === 'radio'){

                    val = µ.exportRadioField(this, exprt);

                  }else if(this.type === 'checkbox'){

                    val = µ.exportCheckboxField(this, exprt);

                  }else{

                    val = µ.exportField(this, exprt);
                  }

                  if(typeof val !== "undefined" &&
                    typeof jQuery(this).attr("name") !== "undefined"){

                      exprt[jQuery(this).attr("name")] = val;
                  }
                });

                return exprt;
            });

            // export argument html field fld to object literal exprt
            $.protected(function exportField(fld, exprt){

              return jQuery(fld).val();
            });

            // export argument checkbox html field fld to object literal exprt
            $.protected(function exportCheckboxField(fld, exprt){

              var val;

              if(jQuery(fld).is(':checked')){

                if(typeof exprt[jQuery(this).attr("name")] !== "undefined"){
                  val = exprt[jQuery(this).attr("name")];
                }else{
                  val = [];
                }

                val.push(jQuery(this).val());
              };

              return val;
            });

            // export argument html radio field fld to object literal exprt
            $.protected(function exportRadioField(fld, exprt){

              var val;

              if(jQuery(fld).is(':checked')){
                val = jQuery(this).val();
              }

              return val;
            });

            // copy all values of the source form to the destination form passed 
            // as argument
            $.public(function copyToForm(destForm){

              var oSrcForm = this.exportToLiteral();

              jQuery(destForm).find(":input, [textarea]").each(function(){

                if(typeof oSrcForm[jQuery(this).attr("name")] !== "undefined"){

                  var srcVal = oSrcForm[jQuery(this).attr("name")];

                  if(this.type == 'checkbox'){

                    µ.copyToCheckboxField(this, srcVal, oSrcForm);

                  }else if(this.type == 'radio'){

                    µ.copyToRadioField(this, srcVal, oSrcForm);

                  }else{

                    µ.copyToField(this, srcVal, oSrcForm);
                  }

                }
              });
            });

            $.protected(function copyToField(fld, val, exprt){

              jQuery(fld).val(val);
            });

            $.protected(function copyToCheckboxField(fld, val, exprt){

              if(Array.isArray(srcVal) && srcVal.indexOf(jQuery(fld).val()) !== -1){

                jQuery(fld).prop('checked', true);
              }
            });

            $.protected(function copyToRadioField(fld, val, exprt){

              if(exprt[jQuery(fld).attr("name")] == jQuery(fld).val()){

                jQuery(fld).prop('checked', true);
              }
            });
          });

          jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery('#pd_applynowbt').bind('click', function(evt){

              // prevent the source form to be submitted
              evt.preventDefault();

              var formHelper = $.new(FormHelper, jQuery('#home'));

              // copy all fields from form #home to form #contact
              formHelper.copyToForm(jQuery('#contact'));
            });
          });
          });
```